# How to load Google's financial chart into a movieclip

Tags: load, flash, finance, actionscript-2

Google Finance has very nice charts to visualize their data, this is one of them:
www.google.com/finance?q=SHA:000001

I've been searching a lot and I learned that there are ways to put it on a HTML site. But I cannot find a way to load it into a SWF.

I think the problem is that seems like it uses FlashVars to pass the data to draw the chart.
(I saw its looooong FlashVars value using FireBug)

If there is a possible way to load it into a SWF, using Actionscript 2, or 3, please let me know. I would really appreciate that.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can access the data using the [Google Finance API](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/finance/).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried that, but did not succeed. I get stuck at the log on part. I couldn't get LoadVar to work. And that API doesn't seem to be providing any data if the user is not logged in.